# android: Listbox flickering when used in looping viewpager

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

I have this issue with my calendar app, which is understandable but I don't know how to workaround it!

i have a view pager used as an infinite pager (page count set to 3, and I move the contents of the pages as I swipe to the left or to the right). I use 3 identical views (view of the events of the day). Each view/day is represented by a listview of events. The listview has an adapter for custom display of the events.

I implement the onPageScrollStateChanged on the viewpager. When going to the left (previous day), when onPageScrollStateChanged is settled, I move the data from the center day to the right, the data of the left to the center and I generate the view of previous day to set to the left, finally I use SetCurrentItem to go back to the center (allowing infinite scrolling).
My problem is that the content of the list view flickers!! I clearly see that I am passing from the page of the left to the page on the center which are the same but the center page hasn't called the listview adapter yet, so when I force the position to one, I have the impression the list is reloaded while it is loaded for the first time...(as it is filled by the adapter).
How can I workaround this problem ?

Some code is maybe easyer to understand:

### Activity class:

```
DayPagerAdapter dayAdapter;
ViewPager myViewPager;
int focusedPage;

 @Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dayAdapter = new DayAdapter(this);
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewyId(R.id.mypager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(dayAdapter);

    myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new onPageChangeListener(){
   ....
 @Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { 
if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
if (mFocusedPage == 0) 
{
   View dayBefore = (View) myViewPager.getChildAt(0);
   View dayCurrent = (View) myViewPager.getChildAt(1);
   View dayNext = (View) myViewPager.getChildAt(2);
   View newView = (View) dayAdapter.istantiateItem(myViewPager,0);
  //move data
  ListView lvBef = (ListView) dayBefore.findViewById(R.id.lvDay);
  ListView lCur = (ListView) dayCurrent.findViewById(R.id.lvDay);
  ListView lvNext = (ListView) dayNext.findViewById(R.id.lvDay);
  ListView lvNew = (ListView) newView.findViewById(R.id.lvDay);

  lvNext.setAdapter(lvCur.getAdapter());
  lvCur.setAdapter(lvBef.getAdapter());
  lvBefore.setAdapter(lvNew.getAdapter());

  dayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}                                    
else if (mFocusedPage == 2)  
{
  ..........
}    
// go back to the center allowing to scroll indefinitely
mDayPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
```

### ViewPager adapter class

```
class DayAdapterextends PagerAdapter  {

ViewPager container;
Context theContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public DayAdapter(Context activityContext)
{
theContext = activityContext;
inflater = (LayoutInflater)theContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeViewAt(position);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View container) {

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return 3;
}

 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

    View newview = infater.inflate(R.layout.dayLayout, null);
    ListView lvListViewDay = (ListView) newview.findViewById(R.id.lvDay);
    ArrayList events = getSomeEvents();
    DayEventAdapter dayAdap = new DayEventAdapter(newview.getContext(), events);
    lvListViewDay.setAdapter(adapSat);
    container.addView(newview,position);
    return newview;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
 return view == object;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

}   

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View container) {

}
```

### ListView adapter class

```
public class DayEventAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
....
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if(convertView == null)
  {
   convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_cell, null);
  }

  //get the event
  CalendarEvent event = (CalendarEvent) getItem(position);
  if(event != null)
  {
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventCellEventHour)).setText(event.getEvDate());
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.tvEventCellEventDesc)).setText(event.getEvDesc());
  }
  return convertView;
}
```

Please give me a help on this, or don't hesitate if my problem is not clear!
cheers

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?